# Update aggregate sum in one to many relationship when child persisted

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

My pet learning project is a simple Project Management / Task app that has the following entity relationships:

Project has many Tasks
Task has many Activities

Activity is basically a time log with a startedAt, endedAt and a durationInSeconds.

Projects and Tasks has a column called durationInSecondsSum which needs to be updated every time an Activity is persisted, updated, deleted.

durationInSecondsSum is an aggregate field for the sum of Activity::durationInSeconds.

My question is… What is the best way to update the durationInSecondsSum property in both Project and Task.

Possible options I've considered but haven't fully wrapped my head around:

**Aggregate Root.**

As described here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/aggregate-fields.html.

Given an Activity::durationInSeconds can be edited at anytime and that the changes need to bubble from Activity to Task and Project I'm not sure how to implement this up the chain.

**Doctrine events**

I have implemented a postFlush event before to calculate the sum in a previous project. After reading more about events it seems that this is a bad implementation that can lead to double entities.

I also considered the onFlush which might work better.

The problem I see here is that I wouldn't be able to calculate the sum directly from the DB given the Activity hasn't been saved yet.

**Message Queues**

Triggering a message to update the Task and Project seems like overkill.

**Duration Service**

A separate service which takes a collection of Tasks / Projects and calculates their durations on the fly without ever saving that data to the db.

---

Any guidance / experience / war stories would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need to persist the sum?
Since you have start and end dates you have it persisted due to the difference anyway, don't you? So at the end it is just a query. Or what do i miss?

Comment: I wanted to persist the sum in the Project which has many Tasks.

Comment: I got that, I was just wondering why? Since a SUM() Query would to that without persisting.

Keeping start and endtime AND the sum, would be considered duplicate data.